# Using fseek with a file pointer that points to stdin

Tags: c, file, pointers, stdin, piping

Depending on command-line arguments, I'm setting a file pointer to point either towards a specified file or stdin (for the purpose of piping). I then pass this pointer around to a number of different functions to read from the file. Here is the function for getting the file pointer:

```
FILE *getFile(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *myFile = NULL;
    if (argc == 2) {
        myFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (myFile == NULL)
           fprintf(stderr, "File \"%s\" not found\n", argv[1]);
    }
    else
        myFile = stdin;
    return myFile;
}
```

When it's pointing to stdin, `fseek` does not seem to work. By that, I mean I use it and then use `fgetc` and I get unexpected results. Is this expected behavior, and if so, how do I move to different locations in the stream?

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *myFile = getFile(argc, argv); // assume pointer is set to stdin
    int x = fgetc(myFile); // expected result
    int y = fgetc(myFile); // expected result
    int z = fgetc(myFile); // expected result

    int foo = bar(myFile); // unexpected result

    return 0;
}

int bar(FILE *myFile) {
    fseek(myFile, 4, 0);
    return fgetc(myFile);
}
```

Comment: your example code looks fine for me. (except when the file not exist, but this is unrelated to your problem)

Comment: seems right to me. what compiler is it? you might try to print, inside the bar() function both pointers (stdin and myFile) to check they are the same.

Comment: @leonbloy: I have discovered that the problem is actually with `fseek()`. Apparently it does not work when the pointer is pointing to stdin? Any thoughts on this? (Updated the question)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502489/ftell-stdin-causes-illegal-seek-error | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063488/how-do-i-seek-in-stdin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly normal that `fseek` won't work on `stdin` -- it'll normally only work on a disk file, or something reasonably similar.

Though it's really a POSIX thing, you can typically use `if (isatty(fileno(myFile)))` to get at least a pretty good idea of whether seeking will work in a particular file. In some cases, `isatty` and/or `fileno` will have a leading underscore (e.g., IIRC the versions provided with Microsoft's compilers do).

Comment: Then I guess my question is -- and this might be stupid -- how would I go about moving to a different index in the stream? I would think there would be a more elegant solution than calling `fgetc(myFile)` in a loop n times?

Comment: @Tyler Treat: There isn't - this the fundamental difference between streams and files.  Conceptually, the input from a stream isn't stored anywhere - a stream is ephemeral, generated as you consume it.  If you need to seek around in the data from a stream, you should read it into memory and seek around there (or, if it's particularly large, read it into a temporary file).

Comment: I do not find support in the C11 spec concerning "it's perfectly normal that fseek won't work on stdin". Do you have C specification to support that when `stdin` is a text stream?

Comment: Change the incorrect "fseek won't work on stdin" to "fseek won't work on pipes, sockets, or FIFOs".  Here is an example where `fseek` works perfectly well on `stdin` because `stdin` is coming from a (seekable) file: `./a.out <a.out`

Comment: Minor nit w.r.t. the comment from @IanD.Allen In this case, `stdin` is not "coming from" a seekable file; it is more correct to say that `stdin` *is* a seekable file.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment.  The issue with the phrase "coming from" is that it evokes an image of a pipe and fosters the misconception that the data is somehow in motion.  People will often think of `cmd < file` and having the same behavior as `... | cmd`, but it is very different.  It is probably more correct to say that "`stdin` is associate with a regular file" than to say that "`stdin` *is* a regular file", but that same language would apply to `f = fopen(path, mode);` and you would say that "`f` is associated with `path`".

Answer (score 3):

Fseek() is based on lseek(), and the lseek man page discusses possible errors, including:

```
 [ESPIPE]           Fildes is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO.
```

If stdin is connected to a pseudo tty, I believe it will have socket behavior.

Comment: Does ANSI C say anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant entry in the ANSI standard concerning the `fseek` function:

> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET

So, possible but with some limitations