# Equivalent of fseek and ftell in main

Tags: c, file, program-entry-point, fseek, ftell

I would like to know if there is an equivalent of `fseek` and `ftell` when I'm working in main.

For example, if I type the name of a file when asked, at end I hit enter. Next I'll ask the user another file name, but there's a `'\n'` in the buffer that was not read. The user won't be able to type the name of the second file because the program will read the `'\n'`. So I would like to move one position forward in the buffer. Normally in a file I would do:

```
fseek(file, ftell + 1, SEEK_SET);
```

I would like to do the same thing when I'm in main, not working with a file.

Comment: Do you mean reading inputs from console/`stdin`? If that is the case then you need to *flush* input stream. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin) for pointers

Comment: You *are* working with a file. The file you're working with just happens to be `stdin`. For example, `getc(stdin)` and getchar()` are exactly equivalent; `stdin` can be thought of as an implicit parameter.

Comment: *How* exactly are you reading this file name? If you use `fgets()`, ti will consume the `\n`. If you use `scanf("%s", ...)`, it won't, but you can't avoid overflowing the array in which you store the name. Show us a [small complete program](http://sscce.org/), and we can help you get it working. As it stands, you're *assuming* that `fseek` is the right solution. You almost certainly have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to use fseek in `main`, you just have to set `FILE * stream` to `stdin`, so it would be:

```
fseek(stdin, ftell - 1, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Your question (and answer) don't make sense.  Of course you can call `fseek` within `main`.  Why wouldn't you be able to?  You're asking about calling `fseek` and `ftell` on things like `stdin` (which have nothing to do with `main`).  That said, it doesn't make much sense to call `fseek` on `stdin`.  Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917801/using-fseek-with-a-file-pointer-that-points-to-stdin

Comment: I knew you had to specify a file to use `fseek`, I just didn't know the file I wanted was `stdin`, that reads the input from the console.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be just to say

```
getc(stdin);
```

or even shorter

```
getchar();
```

and ignore the returned character.