# What is the expected behaviour of io.stdin:seek()?

Tags: lua, stdin, seek

In Lua documentation, calling :seek() on a file object is supposed to return how much data has been read through the file. However, when I call this method on stdin it does not return consistent numbers.

When I open terminal and run the Lua REPL and execute `io.stdin:seek()` I get random numbers. In one tab I might get:

```
Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> =io.stdin:seek()
2091
```

In another tab I could get instead:

```
Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> =io.stdin:seek()
486
```

What explains this behaviour whereby calling seek() on stdin returns a number that seems to have no relevance to how much input Lua has received?

And how else might I be able to retrieve how much data has been read through stdin?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4917849/107090.

Comment: Btw, why are you still running 5.2.0?

Comment: Because 5.2 was my favorite. ;) I had to manually install 5.2 over 5.1 and haven't took the effort to install 5.3 yet. Using macosx.

Comment: I meant, why not 5.2.3?