# What does the following line mean?

Tags: c, input, io, buffer, flush

I was writing a program and had to handle buffers. But when I employed some loops I realized that the buffer was not being flushed after each iteration and withheld its last input value. I searched on the internet and found this code line. It works but I don't know what this means. 
`fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);`

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4917801/2410359

Comment: If you did not find the documentation of `fseek` you definitively should enhance your search skills. It is the very first entry on a simple google search. If you don't understand the syntax, learning C will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It moves the read/write pointer to the end of the file/stream and so it needs to be flushed.

see [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm)

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)
```

**Parameters**

**stream** − This is the pointer to a FILE object that identifies the stream.

**offset** − This is the number of bytes to offset from whence.

**whence** − This is the position from where offset is added. It is specified by one of the following constants −

- SEEK_SET: Beginning of file
- SEEK_CUR: Current position of the file
  pointer
- SEEK_END: End of file

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function

```
int fflush(FILE *stream)
```

on stdin. That should do the same operation.

Comment: have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/6081445 - it should not be used for stdin

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for the full details — there are some contexts where it is OK, but not many.