# Is there a fseek and ftell equivalent from getc files for getchar()?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int o;
    int w = 80;
    int p = 1;

    int c;
    int line_count = 0;
    long remember_pos;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        long num = ftell(stdin);
        printf("%li\n", num);
    }
}
```

Basically processing the standard input when you do it in unix, like for example

```
$ gcc -Wall fileabove.c
$ echo hello | ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want it to process the 'hello' from echo. I want there to be a way to get to stdin[0] (in file's with fseek). Also get the position we are currently on (in file's with ftell)

OR looking for any other way to keep track of unseekable standard input

Comment: what is `optind` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fseek with a file pointer that points to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917801/using-fseek-with-a-file-pointer-that-points-to-stdin)

Comment: Simply looking for an equivalent of fseek or ftell for stdin like "echo hello", if it's possible.

Comment: @Basbas: As the suggested duplicate shows, there is no such thing. You can repeatedly get characters until you run out, and that's about it. Character streams aren't files; they have no defined end point until the stream is closed (after all, if the user manually typed inputs, rather than using `echo`, it would look roughly the same to your program, and the user may or may not *ever* hit Ctrl-D to signal end of stdin input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `getchar()` reads characters from `stdin`, you can use `fseek(stdin)` and `ftell()` on `stdin`. But calling those functions will always fail when `stdin` is not a normal file. Look at the link @lurker pointed.

The following code returns -1 and ESPIPE (Illegal Seek)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
main() {
        long pos;
        pos = ftell(stdin);
        printf("%ld\n", pos);
        printf("errno=%d\n", errno);
}

$ ./a.out
```

However, when we run the same code with file redirection `ftell()` returns 0 without error. This time `stdin` of `./a.out` is a normal file and seekable.

```
$ ./a.out < a.c
```

So the most viable solution to original poster is:

```
$ echo hello > input.txt
$ ./a.out < input.txt
```

Comment: "*But it will always fail because `stdin` is not seekable stream.*" Not necessarily. `stdin` can refer to a pipe, terminal, normal file, socket, etc (it's inherited from the calling process). Normal files are seekable.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, you are right. I fixed the answer. Thank you.

Comment: long num = ftell(stdin) always give's '-1', if it were echo hello | ./a.out?

Comment: if you do `echo hello | ./a.out` then stdin of a.out is not normal file and is not seekable. Try making data file with content `hello` then do `./a.out < data_file`

Comment: So there's no way to do ftell(stdin) such that echo hello | ./a.out would work as wanted?

Comment: @Basbas As you said, No.