# Using FILE *f = stdin;

Tags: c, file, stdin, tail, fseek

I want(ed) to implement POSIX tail in C language. If the input is file (filename received from argv), then I used fseek to get at the end of file, so implementation was somehow easy.

But when the input is stdin, I can't use fseek. I somehow figured out that i can do:

```
FILE *f = stdin;
```

Then I can use stdin as file and fseek, everything works as intended (with some little work :D).

My question is only, is this okay ? I mean (for me) it's kinda unusual to use stdin like that. Wouldn't be there any 'security' or another errors with this ? I tested my tail a lot and it looks like it works good even with edge cases.

Comment: It's fine, this is how programs that process either named files or stdin normally work.

Comment: Is `fseek` relevant with `stdin`? See [Using fseek with a file pointer that points to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917801/using-fseek-with-a-file-pointer-that-points-to-stdin)

Comment: @WeatherVane If `stdin` is redirected to a file, why wouldn't it be relevant?

Comment: That question is talking about the default connection of stdin to the terminal, but if you run `tail < filename` you can use `fseek()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, `fseek` does work with a file redirected to `stdin`. But when you type something, my code waits for more input (using `fseek` to the beginning).

Comment: @WeatherVane It doesn't make sense to use a program like `tail` with interactive input. You need to check for an error from `fseek()` to know if you can use it.

Comment: @Barmar indeed `0` was not returned. *On devices incapable of seeking, the return value is undefined.*

Comment: @Barmar *if you run `tail < filename` you can use `fseek()`*  Not if `filename` is a named pipe.  And probably a few others types, too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Of course. It's for plain files. The whole point is that `tail filename` and `tail < filename` should work the same -- it doesn't matter whether you open the file by name or get it by `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a weird thing to do because it doesn't help. Whether `fseek` works or not isn't  affected by the name of the variable used as an argument.

It can succeed if the handle is for a plain file.
It can't succeed if the handle isn't for a plain file.

This is true for `fseek(stdin, ...)`. (Code below.)

```
$ ./fseek_stdin <file
fghij

$ cat file | ./fseek_stdin
fseek: Illegal seek
```

This is true for `fseek(f, ...)`. (Code below.)

```
$ ./fseek_f <file
fghij

$ cat file | ./fseek_f
fseek: Illegal seek
```

But there is also no harm in assigning `stdin` to another variable. For example, you might do

```
FILE *f;
if (...) {
   f = stdin;
} else {
   f = fopen(...);
}
```

Or you might do

```
void some_func(FILE *f) {
   ...
}

some_func(stdin);
```

These are both perfectly legitimate assignments of `stdin` to another variable.

---

Here are the files used in the earlier tests:

`file`:

```
abcdefghij
```

`fseek_stdin.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   if (fseek(stdin, 5, SEEK_CUR) < 0) {
      perror("fseek");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   char *line = NULL;
   size_t n = 0;
   if (getline(&line, &n, stdin) < 0) {
      perror("getline");
      free(line);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   printf("%s", line);
   free(line);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`fseek_f.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   FILE *f = stdin;

   if (fseek(f, 5, SEEK_CUR) < 0) {
      perror("fseek");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   char *line = NULL;
   size_t n = 0;
   if (getline(&line, &n, f) < 0) {
      perror("getline");
      free(line);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   printf("%s", line);
   free(line);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A diff of the two programs (slightly massaged for readability):

```
$ diff -y fseek_{stdin,f}.c
#include <stdio.h>                               #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                              #include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {                                 int main(void) {
                                               >    FILE *f = stdin;
                                               >
   if (fseek(stdin, 5, SEEK_CUR) < 0) {        |    if (fseek(f, 5, SEEK_CUR) < 0) {
      perror("fseek");                                 perror("fseek");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;                             return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }                                                }

   char *line = NULL;                               char *line = NULL;
   size_t n = 0;                                    size_t n = 0;
   if (getline(&line, &n, stdin) < 0) {        |    if (getline(&line, &n, f) < 0) {
      perror("getline");                               perror("getline");
      free(line);                                      free(line);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;                             return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }                                                }

   printf("%s", line);                              printf("%s", line);
   free(line);                                      free(line);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;                             return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}                                                }
```