# C code execution error on different compiler with unlisted error code

Tags: c

So I'm a new-ish coder taking a C class for school. I have written code to do some very basic array manipulation and it runs just fine within VS Code and several online C compilers that I tried, but when my teacher runs it within Visual Studio, it fails on the first input and exits with code "-1073740791" and that's not in the documentation for error codes in Visual Studio and there's nothing on google and I don't have their machine to debug, so frankly, I have no idea what I did wrong or what I need to be doing differently. I ran the code through several online compilers and even learned how to make VS Code show more warnings to no avail. I've pasted the whole code (it's really short; it's really simple array stuff like I said) and I don't know; hopefully someone can tell me something I did that was stupid and obvious to anyone that actually knows what's up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int inputTracker[3][3] = {0};

int getInput(int row, int column);
int checkHistory(int input, int array[][3]);
int fillLoShuGrid(int array[][3]);
void print2DArrayOf3Layers(int firstD, int array[][3]); //apparently you have to specify the length of all array wdiths after the first dimension unless you do pointer-to-pointer-to crap that I just don' feel like dealing with atm
void validateAndPrintLoShuGrid(int array[][3]);
int is15(int input);

int is15(int input){
    if(input == 15){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void validateAndPrintLoShuGrid(int array[][3]){
    int counter = 0;

    int isGriddied = 1; //if this variable makes it through the checking process and never changes to 0 on a detection of a non-15, it is a lo shu grid
/*
0 2
1 1
2 0

*/

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //calculates top right diagonal
        int j = 2 - i;
        counter += array[i][j];
        if(!is15(counter)){
            isGriddied = 0;
        }
        
    }

    printf("%*s", 10, "");
    printf("| %2d\n", counter); //formats and prints rop right diagonal

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%2d ", array[i][j]);
            counter += array[i][j];
        }
        printf(" | %2d\n", counter); //prints grid, calculates horizontal, formats and prints horizontal
        if(!is15(counter)){
            isGriddied = 0;
        }
    } 

    printf("--------------\n "); //formatting break

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            counter += array[j][i];
        }
        printf("%-3d", counter); //calculates formats and prints vertical
        if(!is15(counter)){
            isGriddied = 0;
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        counter += array[i][i];
    }
    printf("| %2d", counter); //calculates formats and prints bottom right diagonal
    if(!is15(counter)){
            isGriddied = 0;
        }

    if(isGriddied == 1){
        printf("\n%s", "This is a Lo Shu Grid");
    }
    else{
        printf("\n%s", "This is Not a Lo Shu Grid");
    }
}

void print2DArrayOf3Layers(int firstD, int array[][3]){
    for(int i = 0; i < firstD; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

int checkHistory(int input, int array[][3]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //cycles through the entire inputTracker array and if the queried input is found within it, throw an error and return 0 from the function
        for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++){ 
            if(input == array[i][p]){
                printf("%s", "That number has already been entered\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int fillLoShuGrid(int array[][3]){
    int sentinel = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //loop 9 times
        for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++){ 
            sentinel = 0;
            while(sentinel == 0){   //repeat until a proper input is put in
                sentinel = 1; //assume proper input
                int interim = getInput(i, p);               //get non-zero, non-decimal, non-junk int input and store as interim
                if(interim < 10 && interim > 0){                       //if input is under 10
                    if(checkHistory(interim, array)){          //and input is not found within array
                        array[i][p] = interim;      //store input in array
                    }
                    else{
                        sentinel = 0;                       //otherwise ensure another while loop
                        printf("input discarded and reloop\n");
                    }
                }
                else{
                        sentinel = 0;                       //otherwise ensure another while loop
                        printf("Input must be between 1 and 9 inclusive\n");
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

//code abstracted from assign3 as an input verification process
int getInput(int row, int column){
    char inputStorage[256];
    double doubleStorage = -1;
    int intCaster;

    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1){ //sentinel loop that repeats until acceptable input is made
        i++;        //assumes acceptable input as default

        printf("%s%d%s%d%s", "Input row ", row, " column ", column, ": ");

        if(scanf("%255s", &inputStorage) != 1){ //loads input into storage. a maximum of 255 characters
            printf("%s", "Entry Error.\n");
            i = 1;                             //repeats loop if unsuccessful
        }

        int checker = getchar();            //checks to see if any erroneous crap has been put into stdin. i.e.g. "2 32". this will reject that input because of the " 32"
        if(checker != '\0' && checker != '\n' && checker != EOF){    //if the next character after what was taken into scanf isn't a newline or a null or the end of file
            printf("%s", "Entry Error. Too many inputs.\n");
            i = 1;
        }

        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END); //clears any leftover crap in stdin

        for(int qer = 0; inputStorage[qer] != '\0'; qer++){ //loops through input string until a newline
/*          if(inputStorage[qer] == '-'){ //exempt negative sign
                qer++;
            }
            if(inputStorage[qer] == '.'){ //exempt decimal point
                qer++;
            }
*/            if(isdigit(inputStorage[qer]) == 0){        //and checks if they're all digits
                printf("%s", "Entry Error. Junk Data.\n"); //if any aren't, throw an error, break the check, and reset while loop
                i = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(i != 1){ //prevents unneccessary error messages
            doubleStorage = atof(inputStorage);  //convert string into double

            intCaster = doubleStorage; //cast double to int (there's probably an "atoi" function, tbh, but I'll work that out after I get everything working)
        }
    }

    return intCaster; //return the doctored input
}

int main(void){
    fillLoShuGrid(inputTracker);
    printf("\n");
    validateAndPrintLoShuGrid(inputTracker);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input you are providing? What is the expected output?

Comment: suspect `fseek(stdin...)` [won't do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917801/using-fseek-with-a-file-pointer-that-points-to-stdin)

Comment: Sidenote: `if (input == 15) { return true; } else { return false; }` is a very verbose way to write: `return input == 15;`

Comment: -1073740791 is Windows misspelling 0xC0000409, which is the error code for "stack buffer overflow". Run your code with the address sanitizer activated.

Comment: One thing you are definitely doing wrong is `fseek`. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: OT: Prefer `fgets` over `scanf` in the input function

Comment: The whole `is15` function needs to be removed, it is nothing but obfuscation `if(counter != 15)` is readable, fast C.

Comment: Some decades ago, C introduced boolean types. There is no need to write a function for boolean values dealing with `int` type. Include `stdbool.h` and then you can use `bool` as return type and values `true` and `false`. But in this specific case, the whole function should be removed.